# C Client AES 128 GCM encryption with openssl and server decryption inside Intel SGX with rijndael 128 GCM

Tags: openssl, aes

I want to encrypt data on client side with Openssl AES 128 GCM and decrypt those data on server side inside Intel SGX using rijndael 128 GCM. I can see inside sgx_aes_gcm.cpp that it uses the same functions from Openssl.

I can imagine that the tag generated by EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(pState, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, tag) function is mandatory for the decryption to success.

So my question is, how can I transfer the tag from the client to the server so I can authenticate and decrypt the data successfully?

I have done some testing on the above scenario but the decryption on the sgx side fails

Comment: You transfer the tag in the same way that you transfer the ciphertext. The tag is not a secret. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9478/does-the-gcm-authentication-tag-need-to-be-protected

Comment: *I can imagine that the tag generated by EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(pState, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, tag) function is mandatory for the decryption to success.*  Not really - it's necessary for the recipient to validate the data.  The recipient doesn't *have* to do that...  The recipient might not have an implementation that would work without the tag, however.  Java's AES-GCM implementation is like this - it expects the tag to be appended at the end of the ciphertext, and if it's not there, or if it fails authentication, Java's implementation won't emit the decrypted plaintext.

Comment: Then again - AES-CTR is the same as AES-GCM without the tag...

Answer (score 1):

**About AES-GCM**

AES with Galois/Counter Mode (AES-GCM) provides both authenticated encryption (confidentiality and authentication) and the ability to check the integrity and authentication of additional authenticated data (AAD) that is sent in the clear.

There are four inputs for authenticated encryption: the **secret key**, **initialization vector** (IV) (sometimes called a nonce†), the **plaintext** itself, and optional additional authentication data (AAD). The nonce and AAD are passed **in the clear**. There are two outputs: the **ciphertext**, which is exactly the same length as the plaintext, and an **authentication tag** (the "tag"). The tag is sometimes called the message authentication code (MAC) or integrity check value (ICV).

Source: https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/manpki/pki_aesgcmauthencryption.html

**About Intel SGX approach**

`sgx_rijndael128GCM_decrypt` expects a `sgx_aes_gcm_128bit_tag_t`* as it's last argument, according to SGX SDK for Linux.

The function arguments description specifies this arguments as:

*p_in_mac [in]
This is the GCM MAC that was performed over the input data buffer (data to
be encrypted) as well as the additional authentication data (this is optional
data) during the encryption process (call to sgx_rijndael128GCM_
encrypt).*

The MAC (Message Authentication Code) is generated by the encryption process and sent to the server together with the initialization vector (IV) and the data itself. A typical way to structure, proposed by Intel itself, is:

```
* Encrypted data:      | MAC | IV | AES128(data)
* Buffer size:           16    12   size(data)
* Ranges:
* MAC reference:         &data       :   &data+16
* IV reference:          &data+16    :   &data+16+12
* AES128(data) ref:      &data+12+16 :
```

Source: https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel_sgx_sdk_developer_reference_for_linux_os_pdf.pdf

Comment: Note that Java's AES-GCM implementation will append the tag to the ciphertext.